# Taking same output twice times

Tags: java

/*
 * (Sort students) Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of students,
 *the students’ names, and their scores, and prints student names in decreasing
 *order of their scores.
 */

```
package homework6_17;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework6_17 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
    int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[numberOfStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of student: ");            
        names[i] = input.nextLine();

    }
    double[] scores = new double[numberOfStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the score of student: ");            
        scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    String temps = "";
    double temp = 0;
    double max = scores[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<(scores.length-1); i++){
        if(scores[i+1]>scores[i]){
             temp=scores[i+1];
            scores[i]=scores[i+1];
            scores[i+1]=scores[i];

            temps = names[i+1];
            names[i]=names[i+1];
            names[i+1]=names[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i<(scores.length-1); i++)
        System.out.println(names[i]+ " " + scores[i]);        


}
}
```

When i run this program;
run:

Enter number of students: 3

Enter the name of student: 
Enter the name of student: 
a

Enter the name of student: 
b

Enter the score of student: 
c

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

// i got " Enter the name of student: " twice times instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind (not sure if it is correct here) is that you type the number of students and press "enter". It reads the first int (the 3) and reads the "enter" as the first input for the first student.

Maybe try `int numberOfStudents = Integer.ParseInt(input.nextLine());`?
That way the newline wont be added to the students.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the first `System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");` as you are printing the phrase in your `for` loop for every student. Therefore you are printing it twice for the first student (one time before your loop and one time in your loop)

Comment: Also if you are wondering why it prints the way it does the first one is `System.out.print()` the second is `System.out.println()` which prints a new line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to answer homework question in SO. But since you have tried some code, It's OK to answer the Q. Take a look:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework6_17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
        int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[numberOfStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of student #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            names[i] = input.next();
        }

        double[] scores = new double[numberOfStudents];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the score of student " + names[i] + ":");
            scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        String tempName;
        double tempScore;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < numberOfStudents; k++) {
                if (scores[k] > scores[i]) {
                    tempName = names[i];
                    tempScore = scores[i];
                    names[i] = names[k];
                    scores[i] = scores[k];
                    names[k] = tempName;
                    scores[k] = tempScore;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i] + " " + scores[i]);

    }
}
```